# Check numerically the definite-positiveness on linear subspaces

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, positive-definite

I have a given matrix $W\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with known fixed entries.

I would like to check the definite-positiveness of $W$ on appropriate 
linear subspaces. 
Typically I would like to show (numerically I would say)  :
$$
y^TWy > 0, \; \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n\; |\; A(y) = 0
$$
where $A$ is a linear operator.

I use the function @fmincon of Matlab with an interior point algorithm on the following objective function :
$$f(x) = (y^TWy)^2$$
and I add a nonlinear constraint : $|x|=1$.
but I don't know how is it pertinent because I don't see numerically that the argmin of $f$ is 0 whatever is the initialization;

Do you have any comments about this method and/or other methods that could be implemented ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with MATLAB's fmincon, but restraining the search to the surface of the unit sphere seems like a sensible thing to do. Does it work for small examples where you know the result?

There is an alternative strategy which hinges on your ability to complete a Cholesky factorization. It will reveal if the matrix is positive definite subject to the limitations of floating point arithmetic.

These are the details:

Since $y^TWy$ is simply a scalar we have $y^TWy = (y^TWy)^T = y^T W^T y$. It follows that 
$$0 < y^T W y^T \quad\Leftrightarrow \quad 0 < y^T (W+W^T) y.$$
In short, $W$ is positive definite if and only if $W+W^T$ is symmetric positive definite.

Now in the absence of rounding errors Cholesky's algorithm applied to $W+W^T$ will run to completion, provided that $W+W^T$ is symmetric positive definite. If the algorithm fails to complete, then $W+W^T$ is *not* symmetric positive definite. If you can afford the cost of apply Cholesky's algorithm, then this is this a reliable way to show that $W$ is positive definite.

In the presence of rounding errors, Cholesky's algorithm may fail if $W+W^T$ is too close to a matrix which is not positive definite. In this case, rounding errors will cause a diagonal entry to be non-positive and the algorithm will terminate with an error. Depending on your application, this can also be valuable information to have.

Comment: Thanks Carl for this method that seems more appropriate (I have also the problem of floating point arithmetic but I can't say which one is more stable but it's an other question). The optimization problem with fmincon seems to work with simple examples.

To finalize your idea, I should find a matrix B such that :
$Ker(A) = Im(B)$ and then I have to apply your Cholesky algorithm to the matrix $\tilde{W} = B^T W B$.

Comment: @Smilia: You are exactly right. If you have the chance, then seek a matrix $B$ which has orthonormal columns. This will cut down on the rounding errors when forming $\tilde{W}$. You options for doing this include complete or partial eigenvalue or singular value decompositions of $A$, $QR$ factorizations. The choice depends on the properties of $A$.

Comment: @Christian: Ok I have the B matrix whit orthonormal vectors (the basis appeared naturally). Can you explain why is it better for computing the matri product ? 
Besides, do you have some references to share about these rounding errors ?
The point is my matrix W is obtained from a numerical integration of ode. I don't know if our study to check the psoitive-definteness is then pertinent ?

Comment: @Smilla: Multiplication with orthogonal matrices preserves norms: $\|B^T x\|_2^2 = x^T B^T B x = x^Tx = \|x\|_2^2$. This is is good for numerics, because it means that errors in the input $x$ are not magnified. I am have some references on the stability of Gaussian elimination in floating point arithmetic http://www8.cs.umu.se/~spock/scans/index.html but they are old and not written in modern notation. As for your matrix $W$ it is almost certainly possible to estimate the error on entries and the eigenvalues using, say, Richardson extrapolation. Perhaps this is a new question?

Comment: @Smilla: Because you are replying to my answer, I automatically receive notification even without the at character. I do not know if there is a user named Christian (probably) :)

Comment: Ok merci Christian.

One more thing: is it more pertinent to compute the eigenvalues and check that they are $\ge 0$ instead of computing the Cholesky decomposition ?

Comment: @Smilia: Let me put it this way: It is much easier to ask a machine to do a Cholesky factorization, than it is to *reliably* compute eigenvalues. You want code which can run without human supervision and intervention. Moreover, a Cholesky factorization requires a fixed number of steps and then you are done. Eigenvalue computation is typically an iterative process and complications can and will occur.